# php is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: php, c++

I have this c++ code

```
if(i>1)
  {
    std::system("php -f C:\\Program Files\\EasyPHP    12.1\\www\\CarProtectionSystem\\UpdateDetection.php");
  }
```

I am using EasyPHP ... but when I run the code I have this error: php is not recognized as an internal or external command operable program or batch file.

Any Help ?

Comment: can you tell us a little about the environment where this is running?

Comment: windows 7 ... the c++ code is written in Visual Studio 2010

Answer (score 0):

It's telling you that `php.exe` (or `php.cmd` or `php.bat`) isn't in the system path.  Either add it to the path, or include the full path to the exe

(e.g. `std::system("c:\\Program Files\\<whatever>\\php.exe -f  ...`)

Comment: i am giving the full path to the php page

Comment: But not to the php executable, which is what is causing the error.